# Cron is not executing latest file version

Tags: cron

I had setup a php file to run via cron.

The problem i got now is after adding to cron what ever change i made to the php file is not taken in considertion.

it keep executin my first version of that file.

i got this problem after updating WHM.

When i googled someone said it might be because of jailed shell access.

i disabled that from WHM and restared the server.

Still no luck...

Any help much apreciated...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Finaly managed to sort the issue. it was with WHM and PHP.

replaced

/usr/bin/php /home/develgl/public_html/cron.php CronXml

to

/usr/local/bin/php /home/develgl/public_html/cron.php CronXml